# Set Picklist value in URLFOR for a picklist field

Tags: formula, custom-button, administration

I am trying to set a picklist value through URLFOR in custom link button but not able to.
I tried these different options as like below but always getting different error
1)

```
{!URLFOR('/lightning/o/Opportunity/new?defaultFieldValues=Activism_cb__c='+IF(TEXT(M_A_Lead_Tracker__c.Type__c) == 'Activism' , 'true','false')+',Name='+M_A_Lead_Tracker__c.Bidder__c+'-EGM-'+ TEXT(YEAR( TODAY())),Opportunity.LeadSource='Advisor Referral'

)}
```

Error

```
Error: Field Opportunity.LeadSource is a picklist field. Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions
```

2. 

```
{!URLFOR('/lightning/o/Opportunity/new?defaultFieldValues=Activism_cb__c='+IF(TEXT(M_A_Lead_Tracker__c.Type__c) == 'Activism' , 'true','false')+',Name='+M_A_Lead_Tracker__c.Bidder__c+'-EGM-'+ TEXT(YEAR( TODAY())),Opportunity.LeadSource=TEXT('Advisor Referral')

)}
```

```
Error: Field Opportunity.LeadSource is a picklist field. Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions
```

Even i removed all the fields and tried only with Opportunity.LeadSource but not able to resolve. If I am not using URLFOR then its working but I need this condition with URLFOR only as I have to pre populate some fields.

Thanks

Comment: wrapping Opportunity.LeadSource in TEXT() doesn't work?  e.g. `TEXT(Opportunity.LeadSource)`

Comment: @NickCook , I tried like this and its not working `{!URLFOR('/lightning/o/Opportunity/new?defaultFieldValues=TEXT(LeadSource)=Advisor Referral')}` , `{!URLFOR('/lightning/o/Opportunity/new?defaultFieldValues=TEXT(LeadSource)=TEXT(Advisor Referral)')}` 0r `{!URLFOR('/lightning/o/Opportunity/new?defaultFieldValues=TEXT(Opportunity.LeadSource)=Advisor Referral')}` and nothing is working

Comment: FInally if I put like this then its working `{!URLFOR('/lightning/o/Opportunity/new?defaultFieldValues=LeadSource=Advisor Referral,Activism_cb__c='+IF(TEXT(M_A_Lead_Tracker__c.Type__c) == 'Activism' , 'true','false')+',Name='+M_A_Lead_Tracker__c.Bidder__c+'-EGM-'+ TEXT(YEAR( TODAY() ))

)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by the error message, did you try below?

```
{!URLFOR('/lightning/o/Opportunity/new?defaultFieldValues=Activism_cb__c='+IF(TEXT(M_A_Lead_Tracker__c.Type__c) == 'Activism' , 'true','false')+',Name='+M_A_Lead_Tracker__c.Bidder__c+'-EGM-'+ TEXT(YEAR( TODAY())),ISPICKVAL(Opportunity.LeadSource, TEXT('Advisor Referral')))}
```

(or)

```
{!URLFOR('/lightning/o/Opportunity/new?defaultFieldValues=Activism_cb__c='+IF(TEXT(M_A_Lead_Tracker__c.Type__c) == 'Activism' , 'true','false')+',Name='+M_A_Lead_Tracker__c.Bidder__c+'-EGM-'+ TEXT(YEAR( TODAY())),ISPICKVAL(Opportunity.LeadSource,'Advisor Referral'))}
```

Let me know if it helps!